# Software stack install trouble for Intel Knights Landing

Tags: xeon

Intel's new Knight's Landing processor has builtin support for hosting OS and is no more a pluggable card MIC as in the traditional systems. Now when I try to install the [MPSS](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-manycore-platform-software-stack-mpss) one of the step is to detect `MIC` with the following command:

```
$ sudo micctrl --initdefaults
```

I get

```
[Warning] No Mic cards found or specified on command line
```

However, in this new architecture of Intel xeon phi there is no Mic expected since the main processor itself is Mic.

So, my question is, how to tell the system that there is no Mic or how to workaround this situation in order to correctly install `MPSS`. I am using `CentOS 7` and `MPSS` version `3.7.1`. The CPU specs are `Intel(R) Xeon Phi(TM) CPU 7210 @ 1.30GHz` model `87`.

Comment: @Ramhound `lscpu` says `Intel(R) Xeon Phi(TM) CPU 7210 @ 1.30GHz
`  model `87`.

Comment: @Ramhound updated question.

Comment: This CPU has been released or this a Engineering Sample?  Are we sure the version of MPSS that you are using supports the `Intel Xeon Phi™ Product Family x200`?

Comment: @Ramhound well we purchased it from a vendor so I believe it is released. I will try to find the answer to your second question from docs.